# Why can't I create an array with the size of int.MaxValue?

Tags: c#, arrays

> .NET Framework only: By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2
> gigabytes (GB). - [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

According to this saying, I wonder Why I can't  create an array with the size of `int.MaxValue` which is `2^31-1` which is `2^31-1/(1024*1024*1024) ~= 2GiB`.

```
int[] newArr = new int[int.MaxValue]; // OutOfMemoryException
```

Comment: You have to take into account the size of the elements as well as how many of the elements there are.

Comment: Because one int is 4 bytes (typically), not 1, so it's 2^31-1 multiplied by 4 bytes of memory

Comment: You could List<int> if you have unknown number of array elements.

Comment: Also, arrays are allocated as *conitguous* memory, so even if you are under the maximum size, if the allocator can't find a big enough contiguous memory space, you will get an OOM exception.

Comment: Even if you made your array `byte` instead of `int` you might want to consider using _[Memory-mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files)_ then instead of say holding the whole 2 GB in memory at once, you use a much smaller _rolling view_

Comment: Why would you??

Answer (score 2):

> The maximum size in any single dimension is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for arrays containing other types.

(`int.MaxValue` is 2,147,483,647 - slightly larger)

There's also a 2GiB limit, depending on whether [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element) is enabled or not; the 2GiB limit would reduce the maximum size of an `int[]` to 536,870,912 since an `int` takes 4 bytes (and of course of whether you're on x64)